# User belong to group having sudo permission without password but now asking for password

Tags: server, permissions, sudo, password

I have created a group `xyzadmin` in Ubuntu 16.04 server and given `sudo` permission to it.

The `sudoers` file has:

```
%xyzadmin ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

user1 belongs to group xyzadmin

Previously it was not asking for password to execute any command from user1.

Now it's prompting for password.
please help.

Comment: To bypass the password prompt, the entry should read `%xyzadmin ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`, see the PASSWD and Examples sections in `man sudoers`.

Comment: Also, the `/etc/sudoers` file layers, meaning whatever the last thing read in is what sticks. If you have `NOPASSWD:  ALL` set for a user or group etc, but then a little further in the file is an entry that just says `ALL` , then it will prompt for a password and not see the  `NOPASSWD` .